# Expo-AV play multiple audios after one another

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-av

I have a pretty specific question.

So I'm currently using Expo-AV to play my audios, and it works. My issue is that I can't seem to queue them after another.

So for example:

```
let sounds = ["../songs/song1.mp3", "../songs/song2.mp3", "../songs/song3.mp3"]

function playSound () {
// expo-av logic, this works so no need to cluster up the code
}

// Now the hard part, I don't know how to play all of them after another. If I map through the songs it will just overload the previous song and start playing
```

Comment: I don't immediately see any queueing functions built into the library. You'll probably want to listen to the status of the player (see `onPlaybackStatusUpdate`) and move onto the next sound only when the previous one is done.

Comment: @jnpdx thank you for your answer, would it be possible to give me a very brief example please

I'm new to coding and having a very hard time with the documentation

Comment: @ashketchup https://github.com/expo/playlist-example